# SSL error on Magento 2 Sign In for marketplace

Tags: ssl, magento, iis, ssl-certificate, magento2

I am posting this question on SO instead of ServerFault, because all my previous efforts to get Magento 2 issues sorted out, ended up being hacking some or other code in the Magento or template source.

I have configured a basic install of Magento 2 with a theme for a client.

Magento is running on IIS and Windows. (Not WAMP), shared IIS hosting on windows (My own server).

I configured the shop to use SSL, and the complete shop runs over SSL without any issues.

However, when trying to use the market place, I get a weird SSL issue:
"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
This error is shown on the Magneto shop (which is currently running over ssl), when trying to sign in to the market place.

[image: SSL ERROR]

I have found lots of hits on this issue, but all answers seem to lead to a self-signed certificate that isn't trusted or adding intermediary and/or root certificates. This is all based on XAMP, WAMP or native 'nix installations.

I do not understand what the exact issue is. I also do not know how to troubleshoot this further as the error description is very vague.

I would appreciate some feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because cURL cannot find a cacert.pem file from which take the trusted signatures.
There are some ways to set this file in cURL:

•   Pass the cacert.pem file path directly to cURL when making the call;

•   Set the path to the cacert.pem file in the php.ini.

You could follow below post:

•   https://serverfault.com/questions/633644/adding-a-self-signed-cert-to-the-trusted-certs-within-curl-in-windows

•   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97036/magento-component-manager-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-c

•   https://mage2.pro/t/topic/988

Regards,
Jalpa.